# Problem using lift-json and play framework to parse/extract json objects

Tags: json, scala, playframework, lift

I would like to use Lift-JSON (v2.2) with Play framework to parse a JSON file into Scala case classes. I am using scala 2.8.1 and play 1.1 with scala pluging v0.8. To start I copied the code from https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/ for extracting value into classes (Person class, section "Extracting values". When I browse to localhost to see the results I receive

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor
args=
arg types=
constructor=public controllers.Person(java.lang.String,controllers.Address,scala.collection.immutable.List)
 at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:285)
 at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: net.liftweb.json.MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor
args=
arg types=
constructor=public controllers.Person(java.lang.String,controllers.Address,scala.collection.immutable.List)
 at net.liftweb.json.Meta$.fail(Meta.scala:128)
...
```

I suppose Play somehow runs scala commands in REPL mode ( the problem discussed here: http://caffiendfrog.blogspot.com/2010/11/scala-json-lift-web-trouble-with.html ). I appreciate your experience with using play and lift-json to parse/extract json objects.

Comment: Why don't you use the play-functionality based on GSon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from lift-json to https://github.com/codahale/jerkson , problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should look [another discussion about this problem](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/b6d5a00605dd9e36), it seems to be explained :)